# Web Workers message order

Tags: html, web-worker

Is it save to rely on the order of messages passed from the main thread to a single Web Worker being retained? For instance, if I do

```
worker.postMessage(1);
worker.postMessage(2);
```

will the worker certainly get to process the first message before the second one?

Comment: Since this question doesn't seem to have a definitive answer, here's a similar question with a better "yes the order is preserved" answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519751/what-happens-if-i-keep-using-postmessage-when-a-web-worker-is-still-in-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are working with the same worker to post the messages, I think it will. You can easily test this if you want. Make a loop and post messages with a certain order. If you always receive the messages in the same order as you post them, you can relay on it, that this will be the case.

Comment: I think so too. However, I would be interested whether this behavior (which I observed in the browsers I tested and which makes perfect sense) is specified somewhere and thereby save to rely on in all future versions.

Comment: On the W3C they have mailing lists for each specification, maybe send them an e-mail and they will update the spec if it should work that way