# What happens if I keep using postMessage() when a web worker is still in use?

Tags: web-worker

I am pretty new to web workers, but one question I have is, given the following scenario:

1. I spawn a web worker and set the `onmessage` handler in Worker
2. Then I use `postMessage()` in main thread to trigger the Worker's `onmessage`
3. I immediately call another `postMessage` while the last `onmessage` task is still in progress

Then, I wonder how does the worker handle that?

Comment: In step 3, what do you mean by `init` on another `postMessage`?

Comment: @MichalCharemza let us say in the worker.js, I specify self.onmessage = function(e){ if(e.message =="work"){  // some jobs take a long time } }

And in main.js I use postMessage({message:"work"}) serveral times in a row without detecting if last job finished or not, I wonder what happen when new postMessage called?

Comment: @Kuan You already accepted the answer - but if you're interested I added a fiddle to prove it was correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The messages are saved in queue. Workers have, just like main thread, a message queue - that launches tasks from events (eg. click), `setTimeout` and `postMessage`. Here's how it works:

[image: image description]

The same applies to main thread as well as Node.js for example. It's how javascript works.

So to your answer - all messages you send to Worker will be processed in the same order you processed them, one by one.

Here's a [jsFiddle as a test that my claim is true](https://jsfiddle.net/Darker/0bd1dmkv/3/). You will see that although all messages are sent at once, they are processed in order.